# Use of this passive in this sentence

Tags: passive-voice

> 上体だけを起き上がらせ、壁に身を預けていた彼の顔が落胆したように伏せられる。

Why would he use the passive for 伏せられる。? Is it because the narrator is "receiving" the 伏せられる? He's describing a character he's looking at

Comment: Wasn't it 彼の顔が? (And wasn't it 起き上がらせ without る?)

Comment: Yes indeed sorry typos. I fixed them

Comment: So the subject turned out to be 顔, not 彼. Doesn't that answer your question?